# Spark DataFrame vs CreateDataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

All,

We have a lots of file that is in ion format that we have to do some calculations on the data before we group and filter it (their total size is around 1.3 TB, each file is around 200 - 300 MB).
I have tried doing these 2 different ways.

First is to parallelize the list of files from S3 that I need, transform that into RDD[Row]. Then create data frames from it.

```scala
val rdd = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(suspendedList, suspendedList.size).flatMap(chunk => {
  Ranger.consumeStreamToRow(chunk, dfSchema.value)
})
val df = ss.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

The second way is to parallelize the list of files, and write it into parquet files in S3 using AvroParquetWriter. The load it back out as dataFrame

```scala
val rdd = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(suspendedList, suspendedList.size).foreach( chunk => {
  Ranger.writeParquetFile(chunk, avroSchema.value, TaskContext.getPartitionId())
})
```

The second way ended up being much faster than the first one, even though it has to write and read from S3. 
One thing that I notice is that the first method seemed to have really long time for garbage collection compared to the next one, which I think contributes to the longer time it took to actually process the data.

Can someone explain what is happening on the first and second method and why is the second method ended up being a lot faster even though I am reading and writing to S3?
(I set the executor memory to 10GB and driver to be 40 GB and I am using Spark EMR)

Comment: Could you provide more info about `Ranger` class that is being used as it contains the bulk of the logic.

Comment: Definitely. Ranger.consumeStreamToRow reads ion file and convert the data in there into List[Row], while Ranger.writeParquetFile reads ion file and convert the data in there into Record using GenericrecordBuilder and write it to S3 files using AvroParquetWriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you comments I understand that the first approach reads the file and creates a `List[Row]` and second approach spark is used to read the files. Based on these (correct me if I am wrong) I'll explain.

An RDD object only has information about *"how and where to read the data"* not the actual data (kind of like streams or python generators). So to create the RDD, spark will list all the files in on s3 directory and (usually) create a partition for each file and put all that in RDD object. So far the actual data is not even read/loaded yet.
Additional [transformation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations) (such as filter, map) on this RDD just creates more RDD (with previous RDD as source) and the calculation that should be performed. Nothing is calculated yet.

Only when the final [Action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) (sink) e.g `save`, `collect`, `count` is performed actual data is read, and each partition is read by separate worker (possibly on different physical machine).
Thus at any given time a single machine (worker) will only need to have a small part of the data in memory.

Where as when you read the file the file is read line by line to first create a `List[String]` every line in the file becomes one value in the list, `map` method on this  list is used to convert each String object to Row object. And all of this is in the memory on single driver (master) process with little to no parallelism. Hence very slow, requires a lot of memory (and garbage collection).

In summary understand which part of your code run in driver process (only one for each application) and which parts are run in workers (spark application can have multiple workers processes on many different machines). And move your calculations to workers.

Comment: `Where as when you read the file and create a List[Row] all the data has to be read and Row objects needs to created in memory of the driver (master) process in one machine. hence a lot of garbage collection and very little to no parallelism. Hence very slow, requires a lot of memory (and garbage collection).
`


Does this mean that for each file it will load the List of Row to memory on the driver and and try to collect all of the List for all the files then converting it to dataframe in a single machine?

Comment: The first approach will collect the list on single machine, create the RDD (distribute to al the worker machines) and DataFrame on it. In the second approach RDD creation is logic is distributed to workers (each worker will read a part of data and store it in its own memory), and DataFrame is created on it

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I know this is asking a lot, but do you by any chance know if there is a way to create DataFrame from the list of files on each executor and performing the grouping and filtering without writing it to S3 and reading it back out (like my second option does)?

Comment: It depends on the file format you want to read (i am not familiar with ion format). But the recommended way to read files as dataframe is using [DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) available as `spark.read`. As mentioned in [spark guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#loading-data-programmatically)

Comment: If you cannot find and dataframe reader for your file format read each filename as rdd and use [unoin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@union(other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]) to combine them into one. You shouldn't need to write file names to anywhere.

Comment: I believe union is still collecting the list into a single machine. And yeah, there is not really a DataFrameReader for Ion. 
What my second option does is read the ion files, write them all into parquet files. Then use spark to read them all as DataFrame using `spark.read.parquet` and perform the grouping on them.
 I can't think of a way to do the transformation of Ion to DataFrame in memory that is more efficient than actually writing it to S3 and reading it back somehow.

Comment: `RDD.union` doesnt collect to single machine. it used widely even in production code. But i cannot help more without knowng the file format and the code in `Ranger`

Comment: Gotcha! But I think, this also means I am keeping them as RDD, and can't really use the DataFrame API, which might be okay.
Thank you so much shanmuga! I will update the question after I give this a try. But to explain further on what `Ranger` does. Both method fetches the Ion file from s3 then convert it into `List[LineItem]`. The difference between `consumeStreamToRow` and `writeToParquetFile` is that `consumeStreamToRow` load the List to memory and returns it. While `writeToParquetFile` will write it to S3 using buffered writer, hence not loading the list into memory and returns nothing.